# Under what circumstances can a country claim its sovereignty over a previously-seized territory?

Tags: international-law, international-relations, united-nations

Assume that country **A** seize part **m** of country **B.**
After "20 or 100 or 200, or ..."  years, Can country **A**  claim that the seized part, **m**, is part of country **A**?
The question is *not* about *History*. It is about *after establishment of UN*. Please answer the question in the following  situations:

- part **m** *is disputed region*  (e.g. [Territorial disputes in the South China Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_disputes_in_the_South_China_Sea)),
- part **m** *is not disputed region*. The world knows it as a part of **B,** but **A** seize it. (e.g. Saddam seized Kuwait).

Comment: As this question is currently written, it is far too broad. Do countries have the capacity? How long are we talking about? In what forum? To what ends?

Comment: Voting to reopen, as this is not opinion based. It has the "international law" tag, which provides enough structure to analyze this question without resorting to personal opinion.

Comment: Let us give this question a chance; edited the title to make the question more objective

Comment: The question is is great if edited.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **A** can claim **m**, but not just because of the passage of time. International law includes several mechanisms to acquire territory:

**Prescription**: This is the closest to what you are describing. If **A** has governed **m** for a number of years, they can claim that effectively they are sovereign over it. The idea goes: **B** is no longer performing their duties as sovereign, **A** is, therefore **A** should be considered sovereign over **m**.  [This article](http://ejil.oxfordjournals.org/content/16/1/25.full.pdf+html) in *The European Journal of International Law* discusses prescription.

**Cession**: Territories can be transferred through treaties.  Typically, a peace treaty (or terms of surrender) would include a clause transferring territory to a victor. This is less common since the introduction of the UN, but still happens.

Additionally, nations garner legitimacy when other nations recognize their sovereignty. Should other nations recognize that **A** governs **m** (for example, through public speech, trade agreements related to **m**, etc.) **A**'s ability to claim they rightfully govern **m** improves.

Answer (score -5):

I don't care much about laws so my answer will be in context of ethics and logic. Any stolen thing can always be claimed back. This is not limited by time, but evidence of ownership. Since such evidence can fade with time, time is not totally irrelevant, but only indirectly.

If one owns what one produce (which is the only valid support for ownership) and we know for a fact that who produced something can not ever change, then ownership can not get lost by theft. The only other consideration is to protect against claims from they who say they own this or that. Ownership demands evidence to support who is the origin of production.

Register a document with the Government is no meaningfull interpretation of ownership. Appealing to majority when Government claim to own ground which is not under up-bringing of any kind is a logical fallacy.

Comment: How does someone produce a territory? Also, not only "stolen things" can be claimed back (Germany claimed the Lebensraum, Western Europe all of the undeveloped world, etc...)

Comment: By putting ones work into it so that all the particles are arranges in a new way. Thus, what you produce is not matter, but rearrangement. When a Govt claims anything it can be disregarded because never can more than one be responsible for n rearrangement. The first one to rearrange is the owner and if somebody else rearrange again he is a thief. This is the root seeking logic of ownership. It all start by we own ourselves when our parents transmit ownership to us and from there it is all about what rearrangement the body does.

Comment: @SJuan76 technically ancestral german land is almost 2x as big as the current state of germany after WWI and WWII.  So they did have quite  a large parsel that was 'stolen'.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to claim a country owns something. To own means to deside everything that will happen with it and not even two persons will be able to agree about everything about what to do with something without being the same entity. Thus, we can conclude ownership to the same thing by more than one person to be categorically impossible.

Comment: I kinda wanted to agree with you from the first paragraph, but the second one doesn't even make sense. It's not possible to track a single party and then suggest you believe them responsible for the totality of the ownership value of that something in any absolute sense, though of course it is often necessary to act as though one could. Like I said, I wanted to upvote your answer but as it stands it's just too reductionist.

Comment: I believe it is better formulated now. Without reducing we can not conclude anything. Deduction is the only way.

Comment: I understand what your saying, but historically, most cultures have a history of taking territories by force, and most lands have been occupied by multiple cultures/peoples over the course of history. This isn't to justify any particular form of land grab, but borders have always been a very fluid thing. What exactly would constitute 'proof of ownership' within your perspective? What if a particular piece of territory was only occupied on temporary basis such as with nomadic cultures? Again, just for clarification.